# Conditional Probability written in terms of individual probabilities

Tags: probability

Write an expression for $Pr(A^c|B)$ in terms of $Pr(A)$ and $Pr(B)$ remembering that $Pr(A^c) = 1-Pr(A)$.

I understand that the sample space reduces to the size of $Pr(B)$ for this conditional probabilitiy, so the best I can get is:

$$Pr(A^c|B) = Pr(B) - Pr(A∩B)$$

But i'm not sure if that's correct, and it's not in terms of the individual probabilities $Pr(A)$ and $Pr(B)$. Help? Can I replace $Pr(A∩B)$ with $Pr(A).Pr(B)$?

Answer (score 1):

It is not correct to say that $Pr(A^c|B) = Pr(B) - Pr(A∩B)$

The usual expression for conditional probability is $Pr(A^c|B) = \frac {Pr(A^c∩B)}{Pr(B)}$

It is also not generally correct to say that $Pr(A∩B)$ with $Pr(A).Pr(B)$

The only time when this is true is when $A$ and $B$ are known to be independent of each other.

It seems to me that you need some more information. Do you know $Pr(A|B)$?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I don't know $Pr(A|B)$, the question doesn't give any probabilities.

I've tried using a tree diagram to get the answer:

$Pr(A^c│B)=\frac{(1-Pr(A) )  Pr(B)}{Pr(A) (1-Pr(B))+(1-Pr(A))Pr(B)}$

Does that seem correct?

Comment: A tree diagram only makes sense if A and B are independent...

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a comment than an answer, but it requires a picture to understand fully.  If you are told that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint (non-intersecting) then $Pr(A^c \cap B) = Pr(B)$.  A Venn diagram will show that $B \subseteq A^c$ and thus the set of "*not* $A$ *and* $B$" will just be the set $B$.

[image: Venn Diagram Showing two disjoint sets]

We see that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint.  The blue represents $A^c$ and thus the set of $B \cap A^c$ is just the set $B$ therefore $Pr(A^c \cap B) = Pr(B)$.

I'm almost certain that the sets are not disjoint though since if they were then $Pr(A^c|B) = 1$ (since we know that $B$ is entirely inside of $A^c$ thus if $B$ happens, it's definitely "not $A$").

Again, using a Venn Diagram, you can find the $Pr(A^c\cap B)$ from $Pr(A\cap B)$:

[image: Non-disjoint sets]

So $Pr(A^c \cap B) = Pr(B) - Pr(A\cap B)$.  Then $Pr(A^c|B)$ should just be:

\begin{align}
Pr(A^c|B) =& \frac{Pr(A^c\cap B)}{Pr(B)} \\
=& \frac{Pr(B) - Pr(A\cap B)}{Pr(B)}\\
=& 1 - \frac{Pr(A\cap B)}{Pr(B)}
\end{align}

We see that *if* $A$ and $B$ are disjoint (i.e. $Pr(A\cap B) = 0$) then this probability is $1$.  It'also worth noting that if $A$ and $B$ are *independent* events then $Pr(A\cap B) = Pr(A)Pr(B)$ and then we would get, $Pr(A^c|B) = 1 - \frac{Pr(A)Pr(B)}{Pr(B)} = 1 - Pr(A) = Pr(A^c)$--exactly what we would expect from independent events.

You could also rewrite this using conditional probabilities since:

\begin{align}
Pr(A\cap B) =& Pr(A)Pr(B|A) \\
=&Pr(B)Pr(A|B)
\end{align}

So:

\begin{align}
Pr(A^c|B) =& 1 - Pr(A|B) \\
=& 1 - \frac{Pr(A)Pr(B|A)}{Pr(B)}
\end{align}

The first way should certainly make sense.  The bottom line though is that you cannot find this value with *only* $Pr(A)$ and $Pr(B)$ you need to know either $Pr(A\cup B)$, $Pr(A\cap B)$, $Pr(A|B)$, or $Pr(B|A)$ (and saying that the events are independent or disjoint essentially gives one of those values).

Comment: Hi, Can you please answer this question? I think you can help me http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1693969/322103